# How to store a UserControl in PhoneApplicationService.Current.State without throw InvalidDataContractException [Windows Phone 8]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I was storing a UserControl as state, to retrieve in a PhoneApplicationPage (this PhoneApplicationPage can show different UserControls):

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["screen"] = new UserControlScreen();
```

It was working fine, until I pressed "home button" and threw this exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type System.Windows.UIElement' cannot be serialized.
```

I read some articles and realized that UserControl can't be stored in a PhoneApplicationService as Current State.

Is there a way to implement a serialization to this User Control?

To workaround this problem, I tried passing a string containing the User Control's class name, but I don't know how add a User Control from it's class name either.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` is not intended for storing large amount or data or entire controls. Just store the data the control needs and then use it to bring the control to the desired state.